# Как проверить, что строка состоит только из нулей и единиц?

Tags: c#

Пользователь вводит строку. Как проверить, что в ней только нули и единицы?

Comment: Проверить, что она НЕ соответствует шаблону "НЕ [ноль или единица]".

Comment: `"строка".All(x => "01".Contains(x));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярным выражением:

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[01]+$");
```

Если пустая строка считается, замените `+` на `*`.